# Robot and KeyListener

Tags: java, keyboard, keypress, keylistener, awtrobot

(Sorry for bad English) Robot doesn't perform it's task after pressing a key, here's my code:

```
public void keyPressed (KeyEvent e) {
     if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_Z) {
      r.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_X);
      r.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_X);
   }
}
```

Comment: How do you set up Robot class? What have you expected and what have actually happened? Please describe all possibly related information out.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Mnemo, all i did with Robot is: Robot r = new Robot();. Im expecting to simulate key press from the robot, after key is pressed, and this doesnt working,

Comment: A KeyEvent is only generated for the component with focus. Post a proper [mre] demonstrating the problem.